"Is" color extension, and vice versa?
In his mereology, Husserl defines moments as inseparable parts and cites examples such as the relationship between intensity and quality or the relationship between color and extension: I never see a color without extension, nor extension without color, though they are not reducible to one another.
I wonder if, given this mereology, the statement "color is extension" makes any sense—if the verb is can hold meaning and coherence in this phrase.

For Husserl "color is extension" would not make sense because color and extension are inseparable appeared moments as you rightfully stated rather than reducible to or identical with one another, contrary to reductionist's claim that color is mere (secondary) properties of extensions a la Leibniz. "is" in "color is extension" implies identity or reducibility. Phenomenology is all about unity without identity, never affirm, seldom negate, always differentiate, since intuitively you already understood from your previous question that 'common' is not a "given" at all. It's apparent co-is...

Husserl certainly would not equate distinct moments by "is" as long as they are taken phenomenally/intensionally, that would be a category error. But "is" is very pliable. Can "color is extension" be made sense of? Atomists could say something like that. The evening star and the morning star are 'moments' of Venus and we do put "is" between them in some contexts, but it involves a shift away from intensional meaning. And even Husserl does say that "green all over and red all over" is only materially but not formally meaningless.

@Conifold So one could say that the ‘is’ does not operate intensionaly, but extensionaly? I don't understand the last sentence: "[it]  is only materially but not formally meaningless."

"Is" is promiscuous and can be used either way, it can also be used both symmetrically and asymmetrically, as in "a cat is a mammal". The meaning of "green all over and red all over" is not formally inconsistent, like square circle, but only in view of a synthetic material or "essential" law that governs "ontological region" for Husserl, see SEP and da Silva's entry in How Colours Matter to Philosophy.
